# main.lua is not called using Corona Enterprise

Tags: ios, objective-c, lua

I have recently made some significant changes to a Corona Enterprise app I am writing for iOS. The code was using a .xib file to launch the AppDelegate, and I have removed that and I am loading a different AppDelegate in my main.mm

The following is my main.mm

```
//
//  main.mm
//  Examples
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "CoronaApplicationMain.h"
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        CoronaApplicationMain( argc, argv, [MyAppDelegate class] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my MyAppDelegate.h

```
//
//  MyAppDelegate.h
//


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "CoronaDelegate.h"


@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject< CoronaDelegate >

@end
```

And finally, this is MyAppDelegate.mm

```
//
//  MyAppDelegate.mm
//

#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

#import "CoronaRuntime.h"
#import "CoronaLua.h"

@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (void)willLoadMain:(id<CoronaRuntime>)runtime
{
    NSLog ( @"willLoadMain" );
}

- (void)didLoadMain:(id<CoronaRuntime>)runtime
{
    NSLog ( @"didLoadMain" );
}
@end
```

I am not posting my main.lua as it seem irrelevant.  If I am not posting something that is important, then apparently I am assuming that it is not.

When I run the app in xcode iOS simulator, I get a black screen and my willLoadMain and didLoadMain are never called.

Please let me know if you see something that I am missing.

Thanks,
Roger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that somewhere I read that I should remove the .xib files (this was not needed).  Once I re-added them to the project and updated the app-info.plist, everything began working again.  Since I am rather new to Corona Enterprise, Lua and Objective C, I do not understand the details of why this failed and then began working.  At any rate, this issue is now resolved.